# how to get build dependencies from Artifactory buildInfo in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have followed this link https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile to get the buildInfo in jenkins pipeline script.Here I just need buildDependencies for Fortify Scan(need to scan both dependencies and soucre code).Here is the code snippet.

```
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo

println buildInfo.getName()
println buildInfo.getNumber()
```

Im able to get the Build Name and Build Number,but when I try to call getBuildDependencies() its giving error **Scripts are not permitted to use method org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildinfo.BuildInfo getBuilfDependencies()**

```
buildInfo.getBuildDependencies().each{ dependency ->
println dependency.getName() 
}
```

Why im not able to get dependencies from buildInfo where as im getting values for build name and build number..can someone help me out to get sorted this problem...Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should got to `Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval`, find signature of `getBuilfDependencies()` method and click `Approve` to approve it. See [In-process Script Approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) for more information.
Also depending on version of Jenkins pipeline that you use `each{}` method may not work properly ([JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481), [JENKINS-27421](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421)). If your version of Jenkins has those issues try to use old-style `for` loop or wrap iteration in `@NonCPS` method.

Comment: @KrishnaNagidi no problem. Please accept the answer if it helped you.